# Force wmode on flash content with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, modal-dialog, wmode

I'm using a modal window on a client's site where we have no access to the content. The problem is that he has some flash on the page and the wmode for these is not set to transparent.

Is there a possibility to force their flash from our javascript to have this parameter added?

Thanks

Comment: check the third party that provides the flash

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript:

- Find some DIV or other accessible container that holds the flash object.
- grab the innerHTML as a string
- Use a REPLACE to change/insert your wmode setting in the string
- Reinsert the string into the document

BTW: wmode="transparent" is processor-intensive. Unless there are actual transparent portions of the flash movie that need to show-through, use "opaque" instead.